# Is there a way to dump MySQL table rows live? (similar to 'tail -f')

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to (from the command line) continuously dump new rows added to a table?  As a comparison, in Bash we have tail -f to 'live-dump' a file as it gains data.  How could this be done for a MySQL table without a continuous loop to check for new rows?

Answer (score 1):

The [MySQL General Query log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html) can be used to log all queries. If you set the following in my.cnf

```
log_output = TABLE
```

The log will write out to $mysql_data_directory/general_log.CSV 
Youll be able to tail this to see all the writes/new rows written.

Comment: To clarify, I don't want to log *queries* but instead *table rows*.

Comment: Understood. You wont get it though. The only way you're going to be able to do it (without writing something) is to tail the log file and filter out row inserts.

Comment: OK got it. Just checking if this functionality was available.